# tikz-qtree and tikz trees not playing nice with each other

Tags: tikz-qtree

I have the following problem: I have tikz with tikz-qtree installed.
Hence, if I draw a tree with q-tree it works perfectly.
However, I have to recycle one drawing done without q-tree, so that the code looks
like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}]
\node {A}
 child { node {B} 
 child { node {E} }
 child { node {F} child { node {K} } child { node {L} } child { node {M}}}
 child { node {G} }}
 child { node {C} 
 child {node {H}}}
 child { node {D} child {node {I}} child {node {J} child {node {N}} child  {node {O}}}}
 ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

This usually works if you don't have qtree installed, but if you do, then 
the level distance is ignored and the third level nodes z1 and t1 will overlap
with each other. Is there any quick solution for that?

TIA!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.  I had to make several changes to your code to get it to compile and when I did then I found no difference in placement of the nodes.  It's more than likely that the changes I made were significant so a compilable example would really help here.

Comment: First you need to replace `\node` by `node`

Comment: I'm without a compiler at the moment, but I just copypasted a standard example here from SE, since I tried, and it doesn't work if you have \usepackage{tikz-qtree}. Then you remove it, and everything magically works. Sorry for this.

Comment: Not a problem!  It's just so that folk can best help.  Which version of `tikz-qtree` are you using?  Also, now that you have 11 reputation here you can upload images - that would be extremely useful as I'm still getting no difference in the positioning.

Answer (score 3):

I see.. actually I found the issue: the latest version of tikz-qtree has some issues with level-specific styles if compiled on an old mac distribution. I upgrade my MacTex from 2009 to 2011 and it worked.

Comment: Well done for finding the answer yourself.

Comment: @AndrewStacey But how disable tikz-qtree temporarily? When tikz-qtree is loaded, then edges starts only from east, north, west and south. How in the same document draw a tree with tikz and a another with  tikz-qtree ?

Comment: @Altermundus I noticed that but didn't mention it as it seemed a minor point relative to what Alessio was seeing.  I think it's a good question, but am not sure if it should be a new question or an addendum to this one.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Without tikz-qtree, the result is not the same, therefore tikz and tikz-qtree do not play well together.

Comment: @Altermundus This has now been asked as: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66884/86