# tikz-qtree spoils tikz trees

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

When I enable the `tikz-qtree` package, the tree I am drawing with the `tikz` `trees` library looks different. Specifically the edges are no longer pointing to proper places on the nodes. In the example below, the tree looks fine when I comment out `\usepackage{tikz-qtree}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[rotate=90]
\node{a}
child {
  node{c} 
  child { 
    node {d} 
    child { node {g} child {node {h}} }
    child { node {e} child {node {f}}  }
  }
}
child {
  node{b}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of uploading an image illustrating the problem; I hope it's OK.

Comment: Yes - thank you. I didn't have enough rep to post images for my first question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the `tikz-qtree` redefines the command `\tikz@edge@to@parent@path` which is used to draw the edges from the parents to the children.  It does this to include the specific node anchors for the parents and children (rather than them being computed automatically).  To do this properly, it needs to know the direction in which the tree is growing.  This is done by setting the key `grow=<dir>`, which is the "right" way to do it for all trees, whether qtree or not.

There may well be other things that are overwritten by the `tikz-qtree` package but this is the one that is causing the effect you see.  Compare the following example, produced by varying the packages and so forth.

1. Original code:

   [image: tree with original code]
2. With `grow=right` instead of `rotate=90`:

   [image: tree with "grow=right" option]
3. Loading `tikz-qtree`:

   [image: tree loading tikz-qtree]
4. Loading `tikz-qtree` and `grow=right`:

   [image: qtree with "grow=right"]
5. Loading `tikz-qtree` but restoring `\tikz@edge@to@parent@path` (no difference for `grow=right` versus `rotate=90`):

   [image: tree with original command restored]

Notice the effect of specifying the actual anchors by comparing the first and fourth examples: the lines are joined where they meet at the parent.

So, to get it looking *exactly* as if you hadn't loaded `tikz-qtree`, you need to at least restore the definition of `\tikz@edge@to@parent@path` (there may be other things that will come up with more complicated examples).  If all you want is something that still looks right with either loading or not loading `tikz-qtree` then using the key `grow=right` might be the simplest method.

Here's the save-and-restore code.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66884/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\makeatletter
\let\orig@tikz@edge@to@parent@path=\tikz@edge@to@parent@path
\tikzset{
  original tree type/.code={%
    \let\tikz@edge@to@parent@path=\orig@tikz@edge@to@parent@path
  }
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[rotate=90,original tree type]
\node{a}
child {
  node{c} 
  child { 
    node {d} 
    child { node {g} child {node {h}} }
    child { node {e} child {node {f}}  }
  }
}
child {
  node{b}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Andrew. Adding grow=right solved the problem. Just one more thing to clarify: with tikz-qtree, did you leave out the rotate=90?

Comment: @Thomas Yes.  In all my tests, I never used *both* of `grow=right` and `rotate=90`.  For a single tree (without tikz-qtree) they have a similar effect but the scope of `rotate=90` is wider as it affects *all* coordinates in that picture.  So I would prefer `grow=right` as the more treeish option to use.

Comment: Interesting, because if I only specify grow=right, it actually grows downward when tikz-qtree is loaded.

Comment: @Thomas That's not the behaviour that I get.  Maybe we're using different versions of TikZ and/or tikz-qtree.  I'm on the versions that come with TL2012.

Comment: Indeed, I only need both grow=right and rotate=90 using TL2010

Comment: Shouldn't `tikz-qtree` just use `../.code={..}` to override `\tikz@edge@to@parent@path` temporarily for each tree instead of overriding it globally?