# tikz-qtree mangles edge anchors in trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tikz-qtree spoils tikz trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66884/tikz-qtree-spoils-tikz-trees)

When I draw a tree using TikZ, for example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{every node/.style={draw,circle}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {}
      child { node {} }
      child { node {} };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

However, if I also load the package `tikz-qtree` the edges are anchored differently and, arguably, worse:

[image]

How can I get around this? I'd like to use `qtree` but I also want the trees to look nice.

Comment: The package has a section commented with `defaults appropriate for linguistic trees` -- I smell weirdness by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you notes in the comments, this is by design, since linguistic trees (which is what `tikz-qtree` was designed for) are usually plain text.  You can fix this by changing the default `edge to parent` path:

```
\tikzset{
edge from parent/.style=
         {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
```

Comment: I will look into that tomorrow at work, so just a quick comment: if it were by design *inside* `tikz-qtree`, that would be fine with me. But changing *all* TikZ trees, that's a bug, isn't it?

Comment: Now that `tikz-qtree` seems to have a lot of wider appeal, it could be considered a bug. For most linguistics needs the issue won't come up.

Comment: Part of the problem is that `tikz-qtree` is designed so that you don't require a `tikzpicture` environment to draw a `\Tree`; if you set the relevant parameters locally within a `\Tree` you can't override them globally in the way that would be useful for the main user base. (I'm not saying the problem is unsolvable, but that there isn't an obviously simple fix.)

Comment: Can't they define "qtree styles" which the `\Tree` syntax would use under the hood? Then it would not change the behaviour of other trees and would be both globally and locally overridable. That would be similar to the `automata` library then.